# Very choppy, slow page turn after instantiating a page in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a Page Controller in which I have three pages or View Controllers inside. After I call the method that switches the page (ill post down below) and try to swipe to another page the animations run really slowly and choppy. Most cases the view is messed up too with the frame for the view controller not fitting the screen. I think instead of actually switching the page it is making a new instance of everything again, but I can't seem to figure why it would be so slow since in my normal code I am instantiating each view as needed and it doesn't slow down when I swipe to switch views.

(It also takes about 5 seconds to swipe to the next view)

Also when I change views, I reorder the "viewControllerBeforeViewController" method in my Page View Controller so that the order of the views remains the same when I swipe.

UPDATE: I have a camera set up in one of my views. I believe this is causing the slowness as when I skip loading that view everything is fine. However I need to load that view in my app :/

Here is my code:

```
- (void)handleButtonTap:(NSNotification *)notification
{

changeOrder=1;
[self setViewControllers:@[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"one"] ] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[NavView2ViewController class]])
    return nil;
if(changeOrder ==1)
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[NavView2ViewController class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MainStoryViewController class]])
    {
        return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];
    }
    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
}
return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{


if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[NavViewController class]])
    return nil;
if(changeOrder==1)
{

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MainStoryViewController class]])
    {
        return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"one"];
    }
    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];

}
return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"one"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a UIPageViewController with three views and a UIImagePicker with camera control in one of the Child Views.
Here is the link to that:
https://github.com/ShashwatMittal/UIPageViewController.git

Let me know if it works for you. Hope it helps!